# Export to excel missing data

Tags: excel, export

When I export a custom list to excel, some of the data in one particular column does not show up.

I have a "comments history" column that is created by workflow. Whenever a user enters a new comment, the workflow adds the user's name as well as the date in front of the comment, and rolls up all of the comments on this particular list item into this new "comments history" column.

When I export to excel, the newest comment in this column does not show up on items with a lot of comments added.

For example:

[Doe, Jane 5/31/2017] -test 1

[Smith, Joe 5/30/2017] - test 2

[Doe, Jane 5/29/2017] - test 3

If I were to export this, "[Doe, Jane 5/31/2017] -test 1" would not show up in the excel spreadsheet, but the other two comments would. Any idea what may be causing this, or how to fix it? Thanks!